# Синхронизация с git

Tags: git, развертывание

Сам я пока еще только знакомлюсь с git. Возник вопрос, а можно ли, при разработке проекта локально и внесении всех правок в удаленный репозиторий git, обновлять проект через git уже на боевом хостинге. Т.е. когда все нужные правки внесены локально и запушины в git, не переносить проект на хостинг через ftp, а просто выполнить некую команду через ssh прямо на хостинге и забрать все с удаленного репозитория, но сделать это так, чтобы все изменения пулились на сервере принудительно, затирая все изменения до этого, несмотря на потенциальные конфликты?

Comment: Именно так обычно и делают.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну естественно. git pull, git fetch

Comment: а если конфликты?

Comment: Вы собираетесь править файлы руками на сервере? Если да - прекращайте это делать, нет - откуда конфликты тогда?)
Но на всякий случай приведу команду git reset — hard HEAD, она возвращает репозиторий к состоянию HEAD. Выполнив по очереди команды 

    git reset — hard HEAD
    git pull

конфликтов никогда не будет.

Comment: А кто на боевом сервере код трогает? Если код не трогать, а на рабочем не делать форсированный push, то конфликтов не будет.

Comment: > Ну естественно. git pull, git fetch

и хуки на Git-сервере

Comment: конфликты локально фиксятся. кроме того, не держите .git на сервере в веб директории.